# Single table inheritance , returning wrong instance_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created Single table inheritance `brokers` in `users` table.
So in console,

`b = User.find 2` (which type is Broker)

When I put `b.class` It is not returning `User` model but `Broker` model.
Is this the way STI works?

Comment: Those who giving minus vote, pls mention the reasons. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way STI works. When you do `User.find xxx` you could get back an instance of any of the subclasses of User.

Comment: To add to that, if you do Broker.find(2) and the object with ID 2 is not of type broker, it would give a record not found exception.

Comment: All right.Thanks..But somebody gave me minus vote.You geeks find any problem in my quest??